# Typescript generic function which returns the return type of an object containing getter functions for classes

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Can someone explain what is wrong with this generic function?

```
class ModelA {
  static A: number;
}
class ModelB {
  static B: number;
}

const allModels = {
    modelA: () => ModelA,
    modelB: () => ModelB,
} as const;
type ModelTypes = typeof allModels;
type ModelKeys = keyof ModelTypes;

export function modelLookup<T extends ModelKeys>(modelName: T): ReturnType<ModelTypes[T]>{
    const modelGetter= allModels[modelName];
    const PerfectlyInferredTypeUnion = modelGetter(); // typeof ModelA | typeofModelB
    let ThisShouldAllowAnyModel: ReturnType<ModelTypes[ModelKeys]> = ModelA; // Fine.
    ThisShouldAllowAnyModel = ModelB; // Fine.
    let ThisShouldAllowAnyModelToo: ReturnType<ModelTypes[T]> = ModelA; // Not fine. But T can be only 'modelA' or 'modelB', so resulting type should be `typeof ModelA | typeof ModelB`;

    return PerfectlyInferredTypeUnion;
 }   

const ShouldBeModelA = modelLookup('modelA');
ShouldBeModelA.A // This is working tho
```

Actually the type of `ShouldBeModelA` is ok, but inside the function `return modelGetter()` is marked as an error:
`Type 'typeof ModelA | typeof ModelB' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<{ modelA: () => typeof ModelA; modelB: () => typeof ModelB; }[T]>'. Type 'typeof ModelA' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<{ modelA: () => typeof ModelA; modelB: () => typeof ModelB; }[T]>'.`

I feel like it should be ok and I don't really see what is wrong. To clarify, I would like to understand what is wrong, is this a shortcoming or I misunderstand something. I can make it work, so I don't really need any workaround or solution, just an explanation.

Comment: Could you [edit] the code to be a [mre] that doesn't depend on external files or undeclared types?  Some plaintext we could paste as-is into an IDE of our choice and immediately get to work on the issue?

Comment: There's a lot of missing bits of the puzzle, but fwiw if you explicitly type your return value (i.e. `return modelGetter() as ReturnType<ModelTypes[T]>`) then it will do as you expect.

Comment: @jcalz sorry, didn't realise I picked the wrong snippet, I'll update it once SO allows it.

Comment: The compiler can't follow your logic... generic conditional types are opaque to it, so it has no idea what might be assignable to `ReturnType<ModelTypes[T]>`; the basic situation and recommended refactoring is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXO1JW).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It can follow my logic with a simple generic type: "type modelType<T extends ModelKeys> = ReturnType<ModelType[T]>" then "let Model: modelType<'model'A>" will have type of "typeof ModelA", no complains at all. This suggests my logic is ok. What I want to know if my logic is really okey and this is a shortcoming in TS typesystem(currently I think it is a bug) or my logic is flawed and `typeof ModelA` cannot be assigned to `ReturnType<ModelTypes[T extends ModelKeys]`. If this is the case I would like to understand why, as IMO `T` can be only 'modelA' | 'modelB' and it should work.

Comment: Your logic is essentially fine, but the compiler cannot understand it. A type like `ReturnType<ModelTypes[T]>`, when `T` is *generic* (and not something specific like `'modelA'`), isn't really evaluated by the compiler.  It's deferred; it doesn't even try to understand what values might or might not be assignable to it.  It's not a bug but a TS design limitation (there are a number related issues I can link to in github if I write an answer).  Does that address the question fully or am I still missing something?